# Can I replace the integer 0 with a string in a column of integers without replacing it within other integers

Tags: sql-server, replace

For instance, in a column of integers I would like to replace all 0 values with a string '-', but when I do, values such as 2089 become 2-89. Is there a way to only replace the single digit 0?

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Please post what you tried so far and your desire result. And finish question title and what is wrong with replacing 0 with -?

Comment: A column can only contain a single data type; if you were to try to have multiple in the same column (such as by having a `CASE` expression return multiple data types in the `WHEN`/`ELSE`) then [data type precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) would be applied. `int` has a higher precedence than a `varchar`, so the value `'-'` would be converted  *back* to an `int`, resulting in the value `0`. This, in truth, sounds like a formatting question which is a job for the **presentation layer** not the RDBMS.

Comment: As an example, if you're using a .Net language, you could set the format of element the value is being displayed in as `#,##0;-#,##0;-`. This would put thousand separators in the digits (such as `1,000`) and display `0` as a single `-` character, *but* the values would still be strongly typed `int` values (both in the RDBMS and the application).

Comment: @forpas INT data type

Comment: @MarkoIvkovic I have tried using the REPLACE() function as in REPLACE(col_name, 0, '-') which does work for replacing 0, but it replaces the digit 0 within other results, such that 2089 becomes 2-89 as an example

Comment: Say me, how you imagine that place string into `INT` column data type?

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE WHEN integer_col = 0 THEN '-' ELSE CAST(integer_col AS VARCHAR) END AS str_int_col
```

Comment: I really dislike this idea... `2` is *not* larger than an `10`,  but `'2'` is larger than `'10'`. Leave display values to the presentation layer.

Comment: @Larnu, "-" being a CHAR, it won't be possible to get a mix of CHARs and INTs within the same column in the resultset. The idea of the suggested CASE/WHEN is to add the str_int_col column to the resultset while keeping the integer_col on which the sort can be arranged.

Comment: My point is that data should be strongly typed, @Raymi . The column `str_int_col` is *not* an `int`, it's a `varchar`, and thus will be passed to the application as a `varchar` as well. Although you *can* replace `0` with a `'-'` in SQL, it means change **all** the values to a `varchar` too which I strongly think is *not* a good idea. Again, formatting is for the presentation layer, not the RDBMS.

Comment: From either a MVC app or 3-Tier architecure, you are definitely right. In my book, the question is SQL-Server related only.